# In swift Type of expression is ambiguous without more context?

Tags: swift, option-type

Hello I have student class which has some details, below code

```
struct Student {
   let stud_name1: String?
   let stud_name2: String?

   var length: Bool {
       return[stud_name1, stud_name2].joined(separator: " ").count <= 15
 }
}
```

I wanted to check valid length, both names are optional. This is the error message:

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context?"

Below is the line that produces this error:

```
return[stud_name1,stud_name2].joined(separator: " ").count <= 15
```

I'm not sure what exactly happening, If anyone 
  could help me, thank you.

Comment: Several comments here: 1) numbered variables are a good indication you should use array instead. Indeed, you end up making an array out of `stud_name1` and `stud_name2`. 2) Keystrokes are free; use them. 3) Swift convention is to use `UpperCamelCase`, not `snake_case` for variable names. 4) `length` would suggest that the value returns the length of the student (whatever that means). What you're doing is better suited to a name like `lengthIsValid`.

Comment: `[String?]` doesn't have a joined function, only `[String]` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it struct

```
struct Student {
   let stud_name1: String
   let stud_name2: String 
   var length: Bool {
       return[stud_name1, stud_name2].joined(separator: " ").count <= 15
   }
}
```

---

or use `compactMap`

```
struct Student {
   let stud_name1: String?
   let stud_name2: String?
   var length: Bool {
    return[stud_name1, stud_name2].compactMap{$0}.joined(separator: " ").count <= 15
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, It is struct and I want it's properties Optional.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating the value computation. This code does the same but way more efficiently.

```
struct Student {
   let stud_name1: String?
   let stud_name2: String?

   var length: Bool {
       let name1len = stud_name1?.length ?? 0
       let name2len = stud_name2?.length ?? 0
       return name1len + 1 + name2len <= 15
   }
}
```